# How do I apply my custom attribute in an AttributedString in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have my custom attribute here, just for testing, the goal is to swap letters just to see how I can affect the string

```
enum SwapAttribute : AttributedStringKey {
    typealias Value = String
    static let name = "swap"
}

extension AttributeScopes {
    struct MyTextStyleAttributes: AttributeScope {
        let swap: SwapAttribute
    }
}

extension AttributeDynamicLookup {
    subscript<T: AttributedStringKey>(dynamicMember keyPath: KeyPath<AttributeScopes.MyTextStyleAttributes, T>) -> T {
        return self[T.self]
    }
}

func attributesTest() {
    var str = AttributedString("It's a secret")
    let secret = str.range(of: "secret")!
    str[secret].swap = "*"
    // expect 'It's a ******'
    print(str)
}
```

I can add my attribute, and I can see it in the `.runs` variable, but all of the documentation and tutorials gloss over this. How do I execute code or apply changes to the string.

(or perhaps this is intended for other things)

Comment: The `print` uses `AttributedString.description` for output, which does not know anything about processing your custom attribute. You can add custom attributes, but only for your purpose, ie. *your* code will handle it - everything internal will not care about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Custom Implementations

Custom attributes only serve as data storage, they are **not displayed or processed by SwiftUI or UIKit**. Additional custom behavior would have to be implemented manually.

#### Workaround

For behavior as described in the question, stick to extensions.

```
var str = AttributedString("It's a ******")
let secret = str.range(of: "******")!
str[secret].swap = "secret"
```

That would display "It's a ******", while still holding your "secret" data in the attributes.

To improve on that, you could create an extension:

```
extension AttributedString {
    func swapping(_ value: String, with new: Character) -> AttributedString {
        let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(self)
        let range = mutableAttributedString.mutableString.range(of: value)
        let newString = String(repeating: new, count: range.length)
        
        // Use replaceCharacters(in:with:) to keep all original attributes
        mutableAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: newString)

        // Set the "secret" data
        var str = AttributedString(mutableAttributedString)
        str[str.range(of: newString)!].swap = value

        return str
    }
}

var str = AttributedString("It's a secret")
    .swapping("secret", with: "*")

print(str)
```

The print output:

```
It's a  {
}
****** {
    swap = secret
}
```

Comment: hey, made a couple edits to make it more clear that the attributions are purely decorative